# Microk8s TimeScaleDB Installation with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I installed timescaledb with helm from this chart: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-kubernetes/tree/master/charts/timescaledb-single
I did not change anything. When I installed it pod gives this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you use MicroK8s?

How about perform:

```bash
sudo usermod -a -G microk8s $USER
sudo chown -f -R $USER ~/.kube
newgrp microk8s
```

Then try your commands again?